# Webpage distorts when i open it on a laptop(smaller screen) but remain okay when i open it on a desktop computer(larger screen))

Tags: html, css

Am a beginner in HTML and basically when I opened my webpage on a different computer, my layout became distorted and some stuff went off the screen and you could not see it, paragraphs and images get distorted when I open it on my laptop but remains okay when I open it on a desktop computer.Ideas?

Comment: You can add your code here..then any one can help you.

Comment: Show us some code...